# Sonar-runner Execution Failure

Tags: sonarqube, linux, terminal

Currently, I'm using sonarqube to analyse my code. I am trying my project to run in sonar-runner, but its getting execution failure. I'm running in a dirtectory.

> Like my project located in cd /var/www/html/projectname/

Inside directory I put sonar-project.properties and inside the file

> > sonar.projectKey = qmsadm
>
> sonar.projectName = Qmsadm
>
> > sonar.projectVersion = 1.0
>
> sonar.sources = application

In sonar-runner/conf/sonar-runner.properties:

> > sonar.projectKey = qmsadm
>
> sonar.projectName= QmsAdm
>
> > sonar.projectVersion = 1.0
>
> sonar.sources = /var/www/html/qmsadm/application

Then I execute

> @naveen-Inspiron-3542:/var/www/html/qmsadm$ sonar-runner

terminal :

```
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 2.583s
Final Memory: 6M/95M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
ERROR: Unable to execute Sonar
ERROR: Caused by: Unable to load component class org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectLock
ERROR: Caused by: Failed to create work directory
ERROR: Caused by: /var/www/html/qmsadm/./.sonar
ERROR: 
ERROR: To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run SonarQube Runner with the -e switch.
ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Runner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging
```

Comment: Are you asking a question with each issue you run into?  Your slew of sonarqube questions really makes it feel like you're not doing your due diligience and repeatedly posting here clearly isn't helping . . .

Comment: @ernie can you help me to find the solution. I'm in stuck

Comment: @ernie  I want to run my project in jenkins without using github and my project is located in my local /var/www/htm/project

Comment: My point is that your questions are poor fits for the StackExchange model.  They're not showing evidence of trying to do things; e.g. the output you included above has a clear error about unable to create a directory, so what permissions investigations have you done? did you try the -e or -X like it mentions?  Coming to stackexchange and just spamming it with questions for each and every error you see isn't how the site is meant to be used, not to mention cross-posting being highly frowned upon . . .